# Why does the Hog Rider have a green ribbon with only 6 Dark elixer?

Tags: clash-of-clans

For some reason in my troop training, the Hog Rider has a green ribbon across the bottom and is only 6 dark elixir. Why is this? Did I accidentally boost the barracks? It doesn't look like it. Is there a sale going on?

Comment: And... it's over.

Answer (score 8):

It is part of the `Events` part of the game
[image].

Answer (score 4):

**Clash Of Clans Hog Rider Event**

*Did someone say Hog Rider?*

http://www.itechpost.com/articles/67086/20161220/clash-of-clans-winter-update-hog-rider-event-is-live-christmas-gifts-leaked.htm

> The Clash of Clans Hog Rider event offers a very large discount to
>   train Hog Riders. The rewards after completing the challenge are gems
>   and experience. All you need to do is win a number of multiplayer
>   battles.
>
> During these battles, there is a specified number of Hog Riders to be
>   used. The entire Hog Rider event only lasts two days or 48 hours. You
>   could find the details in the *Events* tab.

[image]

*Happy Clashing!*

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? Its a perfect explanation. Upvoted

Comment: This reads like an advertisement. Are you quoting something?

Comment: @Robotnik advertisement in what sense? the "ends in 4hours" line?

Comment: No one line in particular, it just kinda sounds like the sort of text you'd see on an announcement/advertisement. Perhaps it's the 'Did someone say Hog Rider' and 'Happy Clashing' parts

Comment: 'Did someone say Hog Rider'  was on purpose :) always been using it in game too during donations,  'Happy Clashing'  has been a part of my other answers too, i can remove them if it is an issue @Robotnik

Comment: I just googled the majority of the text, and most of it seems to have come from this article: http://www.itechpost.com/articles/67086/20161220/clash-of-clans-winter-update-hog-rider-event-is-live-christmas-gifts-leaked.htm. if you're going to quote parts wholesale, you need to provide attribution.

Comment: Yeah it is.. Updated the answer. Mind improving my answer if there are anymore issues?@Robotnik

Comment: another downvote XD I might just delete the answer.. I really don't know what is wrong with my answer now. I provided the link, quoted it, someone might just update me with the rules of arqade please

Comment: Yea, if someone downvotes you'd usually just delete it.

Comment: Generally, complaining about down votes makes more happen. If nobody left a reason, then the down vote tooltip is a good assumption to make. That said, if you wholesale delete content that has down votes, the system will quickly prevent you from asking or answering anything ever again. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new "Events" tab that was added in the new update. As part of this update, the first event they are doing centers around the hog riders. It significantly reduces the training costs for them because the event requires you to use a certain amount in 3 multiplayer battles. If you do, you are rewarded 300xp and 30 gems (which is great because the next event coming up is a 1 gem collector boost :D).